# Send emails using VBA from Excel sheet with multiple recipients - pull in date and attachment

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am using VBA code to send emails from an Excel sheet:

I use code to generate a separate email for each email address in Column C with a file attached.

I am looking to add code to:

1. Pull in the date from column D to the body of the email.
   I have put in the code for the body of the email where I want the date to go.
   How do I get the date for each email row by row.
2. Attach an additional file to the email IF there is a link in column E.
   This would be in addition to the one already in the code.

Each row in the Excel sheet should generate a separate email using the email address in column C, date in column D and attachment in column E.

Comment: If you study the code you found, you can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume that the rest of the code works, just update the with-block to:

```
With MItem
    .To = sourceWorksheet.Cells(RowIndex, 3).Value
    .Subject = "Subject Here"
    If Cells(RowIndex, 5) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add Cells(RowIndex, 5).Value
    If Cells(RowIndex, 6) <> "" Then .Attachments.Add Cells(RowIndex, 6).Value
    .HTMLBody = "<font face = ""Calibri(Body)"" font size=""3"" color=""black""><p>Good afternoon, </p>" & _
    "<p><strong>Please review the attached and return by " & Cells(RowIndex, 4) & ". </strong>  </p></font>" & .HTMLBody
     .Display
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one more question - the code is generating an email when there is no email address in column C. I want it to skip over any row with no email address - can you advise on code to add? I tried adding If Cells(RowIndex, 3) <> "" before .To but it did not work.

Comment: Hi Sharon, just add `if sourceWorksheet.Cells(RowIndex, 3) <> "" then` before With MItem and `End if` after End With